# ImportError: No module named artist

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-2.x

I tried to upgrade matplotlib using `pip install --upgrade matplotlib`, then after upgrading an import error occurred: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

```
ImportError: No module named artist
```

The whole error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-eff513f636fd> in <module>()
----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

C:\Users\TZ\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in <module>()
     25 
     26 import matplotlib
---> 27 import matplotlib.colorbar
     28 from matplotlib import style
     29 from matplotlib import _pylab_helpers, interactive

C:\Users\TZ\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py in <module>()
     30 
     31 import matplotlib as mpl
---> 32 import matplotlib.artist as martist
     33 import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
     34 import matplotlib.collections as collections

ImportError: No module named artist
```

Anyone could solve this problem? (PS: I use python 2.7)

Comment: Give a try to https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6771/ ?

Comment: i think you are not properly installed matplotlib , if you are using ubuntu then install it with sudo

Comment: create a separate environment . I was getting this error and similar error as separate environment was not created.

Answer (score 1):

When I faced this issue (system: Windows - 64 bit OS) after upgrading Anaconda to the latest version (yesterday), I saw that Anaconda was trying to load the package from a location different from the default site-packages. Hence:

1. I fist checked the path my jupyter notebook was defaulting to as mentioned in one of the git hub posts (sorry I don't remember which one) using:

   ```
   import sys

   print(sys.path)
   ```
2. Since this path is not the default site-packages folder, I uninstalled Anaconda completely from add or remove programs - Anaconda (this will take some time to uninstall)
3. Anaconda will also remove jupyter notebook from your system. Hence, just reinstall jupyter notebook alone and open it from command line using

   ```
   jupyter notebook
   ```
4. When you now try to import the matplotlib.pyplot in your notebook, it should not give any errors and you can use the same sys.path to check the path it is defaulting to. It should look something like:

[image: pathimage]

Now, it is importing from the site-packages folder.

I am yet to investigate why and how this issue was caused but removing the upgraded Anaconda version helped me.

Comment: Long ago I posted this question, and sorry that now I can not validate it, but I believe this makes sense:  Anaconda was trying to load the package from a location different from the default site-packages

Answer (score 0):

Run this command on your prompt:

```
pip install --user matplotlib --force
```

If it asks any packages related to it. Please install them also . It succeded for me. I hope for you also

Answer (score 0):

Running this command worked for me:

```
conda install matplotlib --force
```

Comment: It would be nice to explain a little more aboout this.